# "Cannot use string offset as an array" when referencing an array element by key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to access the value ('Id') of an array.

This is my code to access the array:

```
$value[0]['Id']
```

This is the error: X

> Cannot use string offset as an array

The array that I try to access: Y

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Id"]=> string(2) "42"} }
```

The surounding code

```
$query = "select Id from test where Tags = " .  "\"$chosedOption[1]\""; 
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
    $value = mysqlArray($result);
    $value_id = null;
    $value_id = $value[0]['Id']; // gives X
    var_dump($value[0]['Id']); 
    var_dump($value); // gives Y


function mysqlArray($result) {
$table_result = array();
$r = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr_row = array();
    $c = 0;
    while ($c < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
        $col = mysql_fetch_field($result, $c);
        $arr_row[$col -> name] = $row[$col -> name];
        $c++;
    }
    $table_result[$r] = $arr_row;
    $r++;
}
return $table_result; }
```

Comment: something doesnt seem right in the dump of your array. It is missing a  [ close to "id". Can you show the code of how you initialized the array? It would be helpful

Comment: Is that the array declaration or are you just trying to show us the structure of the array?

Comment: @Jospeh: i think that is the result of var_dump($value)

Comment: Yes I edited. And indeed it's a var_dump.

Comment: Are you sure the array isn't empty? It also throws the error when the array is empty.

Comment: No, he is not empty i'm very sure off that.

Comment: Can you post some of the surrounding code? This should be working fine on the basis of the information we have.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question. I hope that's clear and enough information.

Comment: Can you also post your mysqlArray function?

Comment: what about `var_dump($value[0])`?

Comment: Gives a normal result: array(1) { ["Id"]=> string(2) "42" }

Comment: Could it be so that this script runs twice - one time with empty `$value` and an error, one time with filled `$value`?

Comment: What if you also set $result and $value to null before populating them (clutching at straws here)? Which PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that $value_id already has a (string) value?

Comment: $value_id is a never used variable. It's the first time that it has a value. To surest a declare $value_id as follow before $value_id = $value[0]['Id']: as empty $value_id = null; .

Answer (score 0):

Replace mysqlArray($result); with mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Strange thing is , is that I cannot reproduce this error. Try this ( with $link ) only , do you still have the error ?  what for other code is there on that page ?

Comment: With `mysql_fetch_array()`, you would have to access `$value['Id']` rather than `$value[0]['Id']`.